# При на жатии на инпут страница уходит вверх

Tags: php, html

При нажатии на input(submit) и отправке формы перезагружается страница и возвращается в свое первоначальное положение. Можно ли как то сделать, чтоб положение страницы оставалось на месте после перезагрузки?

```
session_start();
if ($_POST["info"])
{
  $error = array();

  $name_user = clear_str($_POST["name_user"]);

  if (!$name_user) $error[] = "Укажите имя";  

  $log=$pdo->query("SELECT id_us FROM users WHERE login='{$name_user}'");
  $log ->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $mes_log=$log->fetch();
  $log = "SELECT id_us FROM users WHERE login='%s'"; 

  if(empty($finsch)) {$finsch=1;};

  $logos = sprintf($logos,mysql_real_escape_string($name_user));
  $logren =$pdo->query($logres);
  if ($logren->rowCount() > 0) $error[] = "Вы уже ессть в списке";  
    if (count($error))
   {
     $_SESSION['message'] = "<div class='warn_reg'><p id='form-error'>".implode('<br />',$error)."</p></div>";  
   }else
   {
                    $nam = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['name_user'], ENT_QUOTES);
                   $f1 = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['radio'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $pdo->query("INSERT INTO users(logus, mailus) VALUES('$nam', '$f1')");                    
    $count_res2 = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users")->fetchColumn();
        $views3 = $count_res2;
     $_SESSION['message'] = "<div><p style='color:#009219'>Успешно</p></div>";   
   }

    header("Location:http://mysite.com/index");
    exit(); 
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="contactform">    
<div class="user">
    <div class="login">
        <div class="namest">Укажите имя</div>
              <input  class="send_txt" type='text' name='name_user' value="">

        </div>
    </div>  
   <div class="socialsend">
        <h2>Выберите SOC</h2>
        <div class="socbutt">      
            <label class="container1">Soc1
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio" value="soc1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="container1">SOC2
                <input type="radio" name="radio" value="soc2">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="send_my"> 
         <input class='button' name='info' value='Отправить'>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: самый простой вариант http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya

Comment: Spartacus делая якорь, страница тоже будет смещаться, только к якорю, мне бы хотелось этого избежать

Comment: тогда вам нужно отсылать данные по `Ajax`

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что при отправке форма у вас перезагружается страница, попробуйте отправлять форму по Ajax (можно использовать jquery.ajax)